# Google Maps API MVCArray isn't being accepted by Polyline()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple code plotting markers and then connecting them together with a polyline but the MVCArray I am trying to use with the Polyline isn't working (and by "isn't working" I mean that the Polyline isn't being plotted). Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.686041,-80.661621);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("network_map"),{
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    $("input[name='submit']").click(function() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var locations = new google.maps.MVCArray();
        var i = 0;
        $("input[name='address[]']").each(function() {
            geocoder.geocode({"address" : this.value }, function(results) {
                var addrLl = results[0].geometry.location;
                locations.insertAt(locations.length, addrLl);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: addrLl
                });
            });
        });
        console.log(locations);
        var connectPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: locations,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 100,
            map: map
        });
        return false;
    });
});

// console.log(locations); result from firebug
W { b=[0], gm_accessors_={...}, length=0}
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a typo: strokeOpacity: 1.,

Comment: I'm sure. I tried removing it just in case but same problem. I'm able to get the Polyline to work by using the coordinates example on this site http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines

Comment: In that example strokeOpacity is "1.0", not "1." as in your code above.  Regardless it may be unrelated it's just what immediately sticks out.

Comment: It shouldn't matter but I fixed it and am still having the same problem.

Comment: I fixed my problem but I don't have a high enough reputation to post the solution for 8 hours... Basically, all I had to do was make sure the geocoder had finished geocoding the last address before I sent the MVCArray to the Polyline. I'll post the fix soon.

Comment: Ah yes, you'll need to wait for all the geocoding data before you can actually draw anything.  :-)  Perhaps you could post your above comment as the solution and mark it as accepted Colin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by setting a 100ms timeout to prevent the MVCArray from being sent to Polyline until the geocoder had finished geocoding.