# Google Maps API v3 - Using bindTo() on the path of a Polyline -- events not firing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mvvm, google-maps-api-3

I don't others with this problem, so asking...   [The closest one is this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156801/google-maps-api-mvcarray-isnt-being-accepted-by-polyline), but his solution doesn't apply to me.

I am trying to "bind" a view model to a view that contains a Google polyline.  So far, it's been going great -- now, not so much.  The problem is the bindTo() below.  Apparently, it's not "binding" to the property called "points" on my view model.  (It's an MVCArray)  I have no idea why.  Is bindTo() picky about what it will and will-not actually bind to?

```
        this.pline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: this.map,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        this.pline.bindTo('path', this.viewModel, 'points');
```

My View Model

```
var CreateOrderPage1ViewModel = function () {
    this.set('points', new google.maps.MVCArray());
    this.set('radius', 0);
};
CreateOrderPage1ViewModel.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
CreateOrderPage1ViewModel.prototype.constructor = CreateOrderPage1ViewModel;

CreateOrderPage1ViewModel.prototype.setRadius = function (radius) {
    this.set('radius', radius);
};
```

**UPDATE**: Do you see a polyline on this page?  I don't.

http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/v3test/mvc/poly_bind.html

Comment: `Do you see a polyline on this page?`: yes, polyline appears when you click on the map (actually you should draw it by youself). I don't know exact answer but I see some difference: your code have no anything like MVCArrayBinder in example.

Comment: I see it when I click. Yes - OK.  The binder is the key here.  Thanks.  I'm not sure it's the answer either, but it seems to work.  I'll keep the question open.